# scrapy for public FTP site with Authentication data, getting FTP error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, scrapy

I'm writing spider for public FTP site with authentication

I gave username and password for ftp.
Scrapy doesn't handled this request and its giving 'ftp_user' error

```
 # all import stmt
 class my_xml(BaseSpider):
    name = 'my_xml'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url='url',
            meta={'ftp_user': self.ftp_user, 'ftp_password': self.ftp_password}
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.body
```

I'm gettting error like this.

```
 2015-04-03 12:46:08+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
 2015-04-03 12:46:08+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
 2015-04-03 12:46:08+0530 [-] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
 2015-04-03 12:46:08+0530 [-] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 38, in process_request
        return download_func(request=request, spider=spider)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 123, in _enqueue_request
        self._process_queue(spider, slot)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 143, in _process_queue
        dfd = self._download(slot, request, spider)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", line 154, in _download
        dfd = mustbe_deferred(self.handlers.download_request, request, spider)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 39, in mustbe_deferred
        result = f(*args, **kw)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 40, in download_request
        return handler(request, spider)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\ftp.py", line 72, in download_request
        creator = ClientCreator(reactor, FTPClient, request.meta["ftp_user"],
    exceptions.KeyError: 'ftp_user'
```

Anybody can give the solution for this error. ? If i'm doing wrong procedure, please suggest me the proper solution. How to handle these types of spider ?
Note that: URL, ftp_user and ftp_password is correct and in browser we can open it with these data.

Comment: Could you modify your code example? I see you have removed code from your example, resulting in non-working code, and making people given you solutions that address your broken example code instead of your actual problem. Please, provide working code, simplified and anonimized, but something that would work if URLs, users and passwords were replaced by actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class my_xml(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'my_xml'
    ftp_host = 'ftp://127.0.0.1'
    ftp_user = 'your_username'
    ftp_password = 'your_password'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url=self.ftp_host,
            meta={'ftp_user': self.ftp_user, 'ftp_password': self.ftp_password}
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.body
```